# Parse 400 Bad Request setACL

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have an "Administrator" Role that I'd like to assign to all of the User objects currently in my Parse. However, no matter what I try I get a 400 error. When I try to manually add in the ACL via the dashboard, it doesn't save. For example, I'll put in "{ "role:Administrator":{"read":true, "write":true}}" and it will revert to (undefined) on refresh.

**Edit:** so I've tried creating a Cloud Code function. Still receiving a 400 error alongside "Result: Error: undefined unauthorized" when attempting to run the function.

main.js (Cloud Code):

```
Parse.initialize("*****", "*****");
Parse.Cloud.define("modifyUser", function(request, response) {
    if (!request.user) {
        response.error("Must be signed in to call this Cloud Function.")
    return;
    }

    // The rest of the function operates on the assumption that request.user is *authorized*
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
        response.success("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
        // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
            var object = results[i];
            alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('objectId'));
        }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });

});
```

My client-side .js file:
    $(function() {
        console.log("running dashboard");
        Parse.initialize("****", "****");

```
    Parse.Cloud.run('modifyUser', {username: "myusername@email.com"}, {
        success: function(result) {
        // result is 'Hello world!'
        console.log(result);
         },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Before update:
Ideally, I'd like to loop through all of the users in my Javascript file and update their role using the following code:

```
// set up ACL for User object
var userACL = new Parse.ACL();
userACL.setRoleWriteAccess("Administrator", true);
userACL.setRoleReadAccess("Administrator", true);

// grab all Users
var user_query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
user_query.find( {
    success: function(users) {
        // querying all users works successfully
        console.log(users);
        // assign Administrator ACL to each user
        for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
            users[i].setACL(userACL);
            users[i].save(null, {
                success: function(user) {
                    console.log("save successfully");
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log("error saving: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
            });
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

However, this returns the following: POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/userIDhere 400 (Bad Request) for each user I attempt to save alongside "user objects cannot allow writes from other users", although my user is listed under the Administrator Role.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Couple things.. the JSON you listed in the post for the ACL is invalid, it's missing a closing `}`.  Second, you need to use the master key for these types of operations, acting on other users.  Are you writing this function in cloud code? node?

Comment: @Fosco Thanks for the response. I followed on your advice, but still receiving errors. Main post is updated. Also, the missing JSON bracket was a typo for the SO. It's still unable to update in the Dashboard.

Comment: This would prevent the users from accessing their own user object, and should be rejected.  I think a sufficient solution here is to just set a Class permission from the data browser (under the More drop-down) to limit Find/Update/Delete to the admin role..

Comment: @Fosco That's what has me stumped. I've had it set to "Administrator" since the beginning, and I have the administrator role set-up with two user relations. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious. Here are some screenshots of my dashboard: http://imgur.com/a/nQe1E

Comment: Also, it's odd that I can't even query for my Users when using the Master Key in Cloud Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I've solved my problem. You shouldn't use Parse.initialize in your Cloud Code function, and you certainly can't use it alongside useMasterKey. Here's a link where I stumbled across this: https://www.parse.com/questions/usemasterkey-and-modifying-user-results-in-unauthorized

This should really be in the Cloud Code documentation.

Comment: There are a lot of things that should be in the inadequate Parse documentation!